# How @override works in java

Tags: java, annotations

I see that the @override annotation is marker annotation. How does the compiler knows what to do with this annotation? Where is the logic to check if a method really overrides the super class method? 
I guess it regards all annotaions since there a logic free

Answer (score 0):

The [standard documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/annotations/predefined.html) answers this nicely.

> @Override @Override annotation informs the compiler that the element is meant to override an element declared in a superclass. Overriding methods will be discussed in Interfaces and Inheritance.

```
// mark method as a superclass method
// that has been overridden
@Override 
int overriddenMethod() { }
```

> While it is **not required** to use this annotation when overriding a method, it helps to prevent errors. **If a method marked with @Override fails to correctly override a method in one of its superclasses, the compiler generates an error**.

Comment: Yeah I know it but my I dont understand how the compiler enforce it

Comment: @user1409534 It's handled as a special thing by the compiler. You won't find the source code for this special handling anywhere in the JDK source code. You'd have to look in the source code of the compiler itself if you really want to know.

Comment: Thanx Jesper. So Whay if I want to make a market annotation myself lets call it @myannot so how can I define my rules for my custume annotation?

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own annotations and then use the api java reflection to process this annotations.

[this link may help as a start](https://www.baeldung.com/java-custom-annotation)